# Языки программирования - разница в комментах в зависимости от позиции в строке

Tags: любой-язык, комментарии

Помогите пожалуйста с нахождением языка, на котором есть синтаксическое различие между определение коммента в начале строки и определением в середине строки ?

Comment: то есть, что бы эти два типа комментария по разному выглядели?

Comment: да, я это имел ввиду. Чтобы для них был отличимый символ-ийдентификатор. Ну или небольшая трансформация, но тот же символ (то есть удвоение, или надбавка или что-то в этом роде).

Comment: в старом добром бейсике вроде такое и было. Комментарий в начале строки обозначался оператором `REM`, а комментарий от середины строки и до конца - одиночной кавычкой.

Comment: Вот я тоже помню, в детстве с ним игрался. Перепроверю. Благодарю.

Comment: @KoVadim разве с начала строки одинарную кавычку нельзя было использовать?

Comment: Вот я тоже пытаюсь найти первые стандарты языка. Я тоже так помню, что писал РЕМ в начале строки, а одинарную ковычку для остальных комментов. Но формально не вижу такого определения в современном майкрософтском Бейсике, уже можно и одинарную ковычку для всех комментов.  Может быть QBasic ? 
Можете найти с источником ?

Comment: вот так `10 ' comment` писать можно было. А вот так `10 PRINT A REM comment` уже нельзя.

Comment: Теоретически в Фортране комментарий определялся `C` в начале строки, но кроме того допускался комментарий с 73 по 80 позиции. Без `C`, но и без какого-то иного символа. Это не считается? :)

Comment: @KoVadim, REM - это отдельный оператор, поэтому нужно двоеточие: `10 PRINT A: REM comment`

Comment: Не все версии бейсика поддерживают двоеточие. Далеко не все.

Comment: @KoVadim, как и кавычку для обозначения комментария. Если брать Spectrum Basic, то там нельзя было использовать одинарную кавычку, а REM после двоеточия - сколько угодно. QBasic вроде бы поддерживал и то и другое, и вроде бы даже номера строк были не обязательны.

Comment: мой пример - с вильнюским бейсиком

Comment: Интересно, а в принципе, чем вообще вызван такой вопрос, если не тайна, конечно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## VB6

В начале:

```vb
Rem я комментарий
' я тоже комментарий
```

А в середине - только такой

```
ЯКакойТоКод ' а я комментарий
```

## Javascript, только для браузеров (ES6, Annex B)

В начале строки:

```js
// Комментарий
<!-- тоже комментарий
--> и это - тоже
```

В середине - только так:

```js
doSmth(); // комментарий
doSmthElse(); <!-- тоже комментарий
```

```js
with(new Proxy({}, {
  has() { return true },
  get(obj, key, proxy) { return console.log(String(key)) } })
) {
  ЭтоКод <!-- и комментарий
  <!-- а вот это - не код
  --> как и это
  НоВотТут --> СноваКод
  // А так - нет
  КакИТут // тоже можно
}
```

Answer (score 6):

В Фортране такое было (в конце концов, был заявлен же "любой язык" *:)* ), например:

- **C** - Комментарий, начинающийся с этого символа, мог располагаться
  только в начале строки;
- **!** - Комментарий, начинающийся с этого    символа, мог начинаться с
  любой позиции.

Answer (score 3):

Все банально, `Java`

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
//int c = 3;
if (a < b /*&& b < c*/) {
  //TODO:
}
```

Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: коментарий `/*  */` можно использовать и в начале строки

Comment: Я в ответе комменту Вадиму уточнил.